# Allowing FileSystemWatcher and WriteTime/CreationTime to look at sub directories?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory, filesystemwatcher

Been tasked with creating a program which will monitor for changes in any files and subdirectories so I've had a crack in c# Visual Studio 2010 and get crashes when editing anything that's in a folder. 
Windows 10 64bit OS:

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace IDGFileSystemWatcher
{
    class Program
    {
        public static DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Lets Test");
        public static DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Lets Test");
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Lets Test";
            MonitorDirectory(path);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
            //This is declaring the filewatching method, and stating to watch the path declared eariler
            FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
            //Makes a reference to the directory. Although we already have one to the path, the array needs it in Directory info format as can't convert string format to Directory IO form.
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Lets Test");
            // Get a reference to each file in that directory.
            FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();
            // Display the names and sizes of the files.
            Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);
            foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The size of {0} is {1} bytes.    Created: {2}", f.Name, f.Length, creation);
            }
            //Splitting off the intial info from the change log
            Console.WriteLine("\n \n \n - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \n        Begin Change Log\n \n \n");
            //Watches SubDirectories
            fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            //Declaring the filters, I don't really know why its needed for the monitoring of changes, creation, deletion ECT but it is.
            fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            //This is the actual monitoring of the files. These are the methods we call later.
            fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
            fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
            fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
            fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
            fileSystemWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);
            fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
            //Enables the monitoring
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        }
        //These static voids each call what they should be doing (e.g monitoring if anything in the directory is renamed) and is then making a log if it is changed.
        private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}    at {1}\n", e.Name, modification);
        }
        private static void FileSystemWatcher_Renamed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File renamed: {0}    at {1}", e.Name, modification);
        }
        private static void FileSystemWatcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File deleted: {0}    at {1}\n", e.Name, modification);
        }
        private static void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File Changed/Edited/saved: {0}", e.Name);
            var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            var theSize = info.Length;

            Console.WriteLine("The file is {0} bytes and is located at {1} \nThis file was created on {3} \nThis file was changed at {2} \n \n", theSize, info, modification, creation);
        }
        private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
            Console.WriteLine("(More details)File: {0} renamed to {1}    at {2}\n", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath, modification);
        }

        private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Show that an error has been detected.
            Console.WriteLine("The FileSystemWatcher has detected an error at {0}", modification);
            //  Give more information if the error is due to an internal buffer overflow.
            if (e.GetException().GetType() == typeof(InternalBufferOverflowException))
            {
                //  This can happen if Windows is reporting many file system events quickly
                //  and internal buffer of the  FileSystemWatcher is not large enough to handle this
                //  rate of events. The InternalBufferOverflowException error informs the application
                //  that some of the file system events are being lost.
                Console.WriteLine(("The file system watcher experienced an internal buffer overflow: " + e.GetException().Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the top I'm declaring datetimeModification and Creation. I believe these to be why it crashes as they are labelled so they can't see into subdirectories whereas they're being called for files in a sub directory. How would I go about doing this?

The error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Lets Test\This is for folder checking'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
   at IDGFileSystemWatcher.Program.FileSystemWatcher_Changed(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) in c:\users\simpsjsh\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\System monitor\System monitor\Program.cs:line 81
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.OnChanged(FileSystemEventArgs e)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32 action, String name)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: What kind of errors/exceptions you get?

Comment: I should have stated that really, made an edit in the post now that shows the error.

Comment: Maybe because you have there `var theSize = info.Length;`, but the changed element can be a directory, so you get an exception? BTW, you're subscribing to the `Renamed` event twice. Also, not that the `Changed` event is raised multiple times for the same object. BTW2, you can set a larger Buffer. The FSW Buffer can fill up, but you really need to block the event handler with sync code and receive a lot of notifications at the same time before you start losing some.

Comment: You usually queue the events received to a proxy method for processing. In another thread, usually, so you don't block the thread that's receiving the notifications. Anyway, setup some exception handler, so you at least can describe what kind of exception you have (maybe missing access privileges?).

Comment: I do apolgise but "You usually queue the events received to a proxy method for processing. In another thread, usually, so you don't block the thread that's receiving the notifications." is a lot of technical talk that I don't understand whatsover ~ Can't stress enough just how littlle about programming I know

Comment: Okay so cleaned up the code and it seems you're correct with the (var theSize = info.length) being the problem. However, what can I do to replacee this as really I need to be monitoring the size of files.

Comment: You can remove `NotifyFilters.DirectoryName` or check the File Attribute, e.g., `if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory) { var theSize = info.Length; }`. So, you'll read the file length only when it's not a Directory (in case you want to also log Directory changes). -- Note: you have to prefix a nickname with `@` to ping someone (e.g., @Simpson.Joshua). You should take the Tour you have skipped and read something about how the Site works.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the tips on the site and even more so with the program. The if statement works solid though I had to declare the `var theSize = info.Length` outside of the if. Shame I can't get sizes of files in directories though. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Sure, not problem (no need for `@` here, since this is your question and you're notified anyway). The size of the Directory is not provided, that's an intrinsic limitation of the file system, not the Framework's. If you want to get the size of the files inside a Directory, you have to read it (with [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles), usually).

Answer (score 0):

*Answer from user @Jimi*

Maybe because you have there var theSize = info.Length;, but the changed element can be a directory, so you get an exception? BTW, you're subscribing to the Renamed event twice. Also, not that the Changed event is raised multiple times for the same object. BTW2, you can set a larger Buffer. The FSW Buffer can fill up, but you really need to block the event handler with sync code and receive a lot of notifications at the same time before you start losing some.